Excel Circular Reference to take no action on a cell in If Statement
I have several fields that I want to populate on one specific day (let's call it UpdateDay) of the month. If it is any other day, I would like to leave the cell alone. I was getting an error if today was less than the UpdateDay, so I changed the formula for that circumstance to make the cell null, which is fine. But now I'm getting a circular reference as I'm setting the cell equal to itself if today is later than the UpdateDay. I've been working on this for three days and am out of ideas! I have 14 fields I have to do this for, each over 12 months, so I would like to avoid having a "helper" column for each of them. I also would like to avoid VBA if possible.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This formula is typed in cell H7:
=IF(TODAY()=DATE(2024,7,31),SUM(COUNTIFS(SheetA!$MonthFiled:$MonthFiled,TEXT($CurrentMonth$1,"mmm yyyy"),SheetA!$CurrentStatus:$CurrentStatus,"Active")),IF(TODAY()<DATE(2024,7,31),"",H7))
As stated above, I was hoping for today it would just leave yesterday's values alone. But I'm getting a circular reference error.

Circular reference warning can be switched off. Details Microsoft remove or allow circular reference

@Blackcat, with circular ref allowed, wouldn't the formula return 0 since there's no other value for H7?

We spoke about this previously, you need to direct the H7 part of the formula wherever the value is being put. The circular reference is caused by the cell pointing to itself or another cell that's dependent on its value.
